Some Membership Contributions stay as pending
Usually, the membership contribution form changes to membership status new when the payment is made which is expected behavior. However, a decent number of times, if a member fills out the contribution form, their status remains as pending (Incomplete Transaction) even though I can see the payment come through on Stripe.
I'm on civicrm 5.68, using the  Stripe Payment Processor plugin version 6.10.2, and on wordpress.
Thank you
--Edit--
There isn't a problem as far as I can see in the webhooks. In the system status dashboard, it says 0 failed Stripe payments. Right now, I can see 20 memberships where the membership status was successfully changed from pending to new. And there are 10 memberships where payment was taken and there was no update from pending to new (it is still pending). Should be noted that all memberships are recurring.

i think you need to add some more details about the workflow. You say 'their status remains as pending (incomplete) which suggests to me they have submitted the membership form. are you saying they then go back to use it again and is has no effect on the membership?

oh maybe you are saying, they submit the form, civi records it as an incomplete payment but stripe takes the money? any errors showing in your System Status. or in the logs via https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-log-viewer if you want to view these via UI

The second one is what I am trying to say. The membership statuses are not updating sometimes from pending even though payments were taken.There was no error in the logs related to membership payment. however looking at the webhook logs, for the payments that aren't changing the status from pending even though the payment went through , I see the following: "doChargeSucceeded: ignoring - contribution has recur" followed by "doInvoicePaid: No contributionRecur record found in CiviCRM. Ignored"

There is a new version of the stripe payment processor plugin available (6.11.2), but I don't get a prompt to update on the civicrm dashboard. I don't want to delete the plugin and reinstall since it might break something or affect the recurring payments already made. I'm not sure if the new version would fix this problem or not either.

perhaps open an issue on the extension. but when it says 'contribution has recur', do those contacts already have a recurring contribution in civi, or a subscription in stripe?

Not an existing one prior to registering for a membership, but afterwards, I can see a recurring contribution where the status is pending.
